# Grid colums having different size with grid layout

Tags: css, css-grid, resizable

I’m trying to build a resizable table (i.e.: columns and rows must be resizable) using the grid layout. I would like that initial columns sizes are automatically adjusted based on the max cell content, like it happens with *traditional* tables.
I tried different ways to set the *grid-template-columns* parameter, but none of them works appropriately: in some case the cells of the same columns hasn’t the same size in other ones **all** the columns have the same size.
Maybe *grid-template-columns* isn’t the only parameter to consider. Can anyone give me any suggestion for the solution? 
Here is a simplyfied example of my table:

```css
.resizable_table {
 display:inline-grid;
 grid-template-columns:auto;
}
.thead {
 background-color:#e6e6ff;
 border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}

.resizable_row {
 display:inline-grid;
 grid-template-columns:auto 1px auto 1px auto 1px auto 1px ; 
 min-height:30px;
 justify-content:start;
}
   
.resizable_cell {
 min-width:100px;
}
.hfiller{
 background-color:blue;
 cursor:col-resize;
}
.vfiller {
 background-color:blue;
 height:1px;
 cursor:row-resize;
}
```

```html
<div id="table2" class="resizable_table">
 <div class="thead">
  <div class="resizable_row">
   <div class="resizable_cell">title</div><div class="hfiller"></div>
   <div class="resizable_cell">author</div><div class="hfiller"></div>
   <div class="resizable_cell">year</div><div class="hfiller"></div>
   <div class="resizable_cell">price</div><div class="hfiller"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="tbody">
  <div class="resizable_row">
   <div class="resizable_cell">La mirabolante avventura di John Lempriere, erudito nel secolo dei lumi</div><div class="hfiller"></div>
   <div class="resizable_cell">Lawrence Norfolk</div><div class="hfiller"></div>
   <div class="resizable_cell">1996</div><div class="hfiller"></div>
   <div class="resizable_cell">30.00</div><div class="hfiller"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="vfiller"></div>
  <div class="resizable_row">
   <div class="resizable_cell">The Green Mile</div><div class="hfiller"></div>
   <div class="resizable_cell">Stephen King</div><div class="hfiller"></div>
   <div class="resizable_cell">1996</div><div class="hfiller"></div>
   <div class="resizable_cell">30.00</div><div class="hfiller"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="vfiller"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the purpose of the `filler` divs are serving but something like this seems simpler.

```css
.resizable_table {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
}

.thead {
  background-color: #e6e6ff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

.resizable_row {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, min-content);
  min-height: 30px;
  justify-content: start;
}

.resizable_cell {
  min-width: 100px;
}

.hfiller {
  background-color: blue;
  cursor: col-resize;
}

.vfiller {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 1px;
  cursor: row-resize;
}
```

```html
<div id="table2" class="resizable_table">
  <div class="thead">
    <div class="resizable_row">
      <div class="resizable_cell">title</div>
      <div class="resizable_cell">author</div>
      <div class="resizable_cell">year</div>
      <div class="resizable_cell">price</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tbody">
    <div class="resizable_row">
      <div class="resizable_cell">La mirabolante avventura di John Lempriere, erudito nel secolo dei lumi</div>
      <div class="resizable_cell">Lawrence Norfolk</div>
      <div class="resizable_cell">1996</div>
      <div class="resizable_cell">30.00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="resizable_row">
      <div class="resizable_cell">The Green Mile</div>
      <div class="resizable_cell">Stephen King</div>
      <div class="resizable_cell">1996</div>
      <div class="resizable_cell">30.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D, but is not working properly: in this case all the columns have the same width; what I need, instead, is the first columnlarger than the other ones (because the first cell of the first row content is very large), as it happens with table tags.